# How to check network connection in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

this code is to check if internet connection is available or not.If internet connection is available then username and password should get validated from server database i.e send request method should get called and if not then username and password should get validated from local database i.e check method should get called.but the prob here is when the internet is off then also it gets into the send request method instead of getting in check nethod.What may be the prob.Please help me in solving this problem. i have added reachability files and imported the CFNetwork.framework.

```
- (void) showNetWorkAlert { 

   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO; 
   UIAlertView *networkAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Network connection unavailable." 
                                            delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Retry", nil]; 
   [networkAlert show]; 
   [networkAlert release]; 
} 



#pragma mark To Check Network Connection. 
- (BOOL) currentNetworkStatus { 
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES; 
   BOOL connected; 
   const char *host = "www.apple.com"; 
   SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, host); 
   SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags; 
   connected = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags); 
   BOOL isConnected = YES; 
   isConnected = connected && (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) && !(flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired); 
   CFRelease(reachability); 

   if(!isConnected) { 
      // sleep(1); 
      [self showNetWorkAlert]; 
      //[self check];
   } 
   else 
      return isConnected; 
   //[self sendRequest];
   return isConnected; 
}


-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
   //[self sendRequest];
   //[[Reachability sharedReachability] setHostName:kHostName];
   //Set Reachability class to notifiy app when the network status changes.
   //[[Reachability sharedReachability] setNetworkStatusNotificationsEnabled:YES];
   //Set a method to be called when a notification is sent.
   //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:@"kNetworkReachabilityChangedNotification" object:nil];
   //[self updateStatus];
   //[self sendRequest];
   //NSLog(<#NSString *format#>)
   //this is to select username and password from database.
   //[self check];
   if ([self currentNetworkStatus]) { 
      [self sendRequest];
   }
   else {
      [self check];
   }





}
```

Comment: @alan i run this code but it run only first time proper if i close application and run again then it will not run proper why what mistack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rocky your code is right .Just check the URL is proper or not .
there is other way also 
On button check the host like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                                     name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        hostReach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"]retain];
        [hostReach startNotifier];
```

and in the (reachabilityChanged:) method call make like this

```
-(void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification*)note
{
    static BOOL showNotConnnected =NO;
    Reachability *curReach =[note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass:[Reachability class]]);
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(netStatus != NotReachable)
    {
        UIAlertView *notconnect1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Server is  connected" message:@"Server is connected" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil];
        [notconnect1 show];
        [notconnect1 release];

    }
    else if(showNotConnnected == NO)
    {
        showNotConnnected =YES;
        UIAlertView *notconnect = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Server is Not connected" message:@"Server may be slow or not connected" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil];
        [notconnect show];
        [notconnect release];
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: this will help Harish is right Just put the code and check it out 1st

Answer (score 1):

I do think there is a sample code called Reachability from apple can help you. see the URL below

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I don't think he should do so many code work himself. With Apple's sample, a few lines of code can do the network check. Just do what apple do in their sample code is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Apple's reachability code to check for a connection to the Internet. There is a sample project you can get from them in the iOS Developer Portal.

Answer (score 0):

Reachability should not be used to detect if the network is available before making a network request because the act of making a network request can bring up the network if needed. Reachability should only be used to detect when the network becomes available after being unavailable.

Just try making the network request -- you'll get an error back if the network is unavailable. Usually the response will come back right away, but if the network is spotty it can take a while, so you shouldn't ever make synchronous network calls on the main thread. Use NSURLConnection if possible and you'll get callbacks when something happens.